# how to do form validation using smart wizard js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, smart-wizard

I did a form validation using smart wizard js but in the second step previous not showing. next button showing twice step container:

[image]

As you can check with the image.

http://techlaboratory.net/smartwizard/demo/validation

Comment: There is a new version of SmartWizard  is available and seems this issue wont be exists anymore.